# How to check current guard in LoginController?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I have been developing a multi-auth based application and I need to redirect to a dynamic location on `logout` based on the user's guard. The problem is when I try to check the current auth guard; it always returns false. I have overridden the logout function in the default `LoginController`.

**LoginController.php**

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function logout()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('manager')->check()) {
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect('/manager/login');
        }

        if (Auth::guard('employee')->check()) {
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect('/login');
        }

        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:manager')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using laravel native auth, there are no other solution but to cycle through all guards to find the one you need.

You can make it more "clean" and dynamic

```php
public function logout()
{
    $guards = ['manager', 'employee', ''];

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            Auth::guard($guard)->logout();
            return $this->redirectLoggedOut($guard);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/login');
}


public function redirectLoggedOut($guard)
{
    switch($guard) {
        case 'manager':
            return redirect('/manager/login');
        default:
            return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! It works. But why can't we check the guards separately?

Comment: @ZainFarooq cause there is no info in session of which guard is being used. so you need to cycle.